C++: unable to catch null pointer exception in fprintf on Windows
my application crashed on release on a fprintf on null stream, and even if I added the catcher:
    #include <windows.h>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <errhandlingapi.h>
    
    void errorCatcher()
    {
        std::cout << "Caught!\n";
    }
    
    LONG windowsErrorCatcher(_EXCEPTION_POINTERS*)
    {
        std::cout << "Caught 2!\n";
        return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;
    }
    
    int main()
    {
        SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(windowsErrorCatcher);
        set_unexpected(errorCatcher);
        set_terminate(errorCatcher);
    
        fprintf(nullptr, "hello"); //<<??
    
        std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    }

maybe there is another method to catch it?

fprintf is not mandated by the standard to throw any exceptions.

A segmentation fault (using an invalid address) is not a C++ exception.  It is a bug so just fix it.

I don't know what you think that std::set_unexpected and std::set_terminate do, but it's unlikely to do what you expect.

You're calling a "C" function, And "C" doesn't do exceptions. Calling it with a nullptr... asking for trouble (undefined behavior). Also you're totally ignoring the return value of fprintf? May I ask you why you are even using fprintf to try to write to a file instead of using std::ofstream? Are you just trying to break stuff?

Hey, folks, this is a question about coding for Windows; Windows has its own notion of exceptions, and MS's compiler supports them. Knee-jerk reactions about C++ exceptions totally miss the point. I don't know enough about MS's abomination to be helpful, but the question deserves an answer from someone who knows what this is about, not passive-aggressive comments that don't take that into account.

@PeteBecker This question was not tagged with any OS related tags when these comments were posted.

From the first paragraph of documentation here  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/fprintf-fprintf-l-fwprintf-fwprintf-l?view=msvc-170: Each of these functions returns a negative value instead when an output error occurs. If stream or format is NULL, these functions invoke the invalid parameter handler, as described in Parameter validation. If execution is allowed to continue, the functions return -1 and set errno to EINVAL. Just follow the documentation about invalid parameter handlers.

@Mestkon #include <windows.h> ... cmon mate.

Doing a std::cout << ... from inside an unhandled exception filter is not a great idea. cout is not reentrant.

@Mestkon -- #include <windows.h> might be a clue, not to mention that call to SetUnhandledExceptionFilter, the use of LONG, _EXCEPTION_POINTERS, and EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH. When you encounter code you don't recognize, don't assume that you understand what it's supposed to do.

@PeteBecker That is the point. I did not assume I understood anything about code I didn't recognize (even though I do in fact recognize this as windows constructs). With nothing specifying that this is a windows system, this could be anything. Anyone can make a header file named windows.h on any system and include that. They could even define these types and functions within that header file such that this code makes sense.

it is very old code, i created here a simply use case extracted from a very big code base.  Yes, it is windows. My goal is to create a minidump file on crashes (the code already does it) so if the program crashes I can say to user send me the dump file.

@Mestkon -- good one. #include <windows.h> didn't refer to the obvious, by far most common, "windows.h", and, despite the Windows-specific identifiers used throughout the code, it could have referred to some user-defined header? And that justifies insisting that the code in the question could only be interpreted as standard C++ code? Give it up before you start to look foolish.

It's not clear what behavior you are observing with the code in the
question.  When I run that program (after fixing the syntax error that
set_unexpected is in std::), I see it print:
Caught 2!

before popping up the "stopped working" dialog:

The message indicates the exception is being caught.  Perhaps you did
not notice the message since the dialog covered it, or perhaps your
program did not flush its standard output stream before terminating
(that behavior is implementation-dependent).  In the latter case you
could fix it by explicitly flushing the output, for example with
std::endl.
The dialog appears because, evidently, returning EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH
causes that behavior.  The documentation for
SetUnhandledExceptionFilter
(SUEF) describes that return value as follows:

Proceed with normal execution of UnhandledExceptionFilter. That means
obeying the SetErrorMode flags, or invoking the Application Error
pop-up message box.

Recovering from the error
Extrapolating a bit, what you might be hoping to do is recover from a
null pointer dereference rather than terminate (with or without that
dialog).  To do that:

Someplace near the start of the program, call
setjmp
to save the CPU (thread) state to something you can return to.

Inside the exception handler, call
longjmp
to return to that state.

At the call site to setjmp put the recovery code in the appropriate
branch of the if statement that calls it.


Note: The documentation for SUEF does not explicitly say that calling
longjmp from a handler is supported behavior, but it seems to work
fine.  The alternative is to manually copy system-specific register
values from the jmp_buf into the exception context and then return
EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION.
In contrast to catching a C++ language exception, one must be very
careful about recovery from a low-level exception such as an access
violation / segfault.  There may be broken data structure invariants in
the C++ library or elsewhere.  What I recommend is that the recovery
code do the minimum necessary to save debugging information to disk, and
then restart the program if appropriate, rather than trying to continue
doing useful computation in the original process.
Complete example
Here is a complete program demonstrating recovery (without any restart
logic):
// catch-segfault.cc
// Demonstrate catching and recovering from a segfault under Windows.

#include <csetjmp>           // setjmp, std::{longjmp, jmp_buf}
#include <iomanip>           // std::{dec, hex}
#include <iostream>          // std::{cout, endl}

#include <stdio.h>           // ::fprintf

// Although the documentation explains that SEUF is declared in
// `errhandlingapi.h`, it also says to include windows.h to get it.
#include <windows.h>         // SetUnhandledExceptionFilter


// Saved processor state we can return to.
std::jmp_buf g_savedContext{};
bool g_savedContextIsValid = false;

// Exception handler/filter that was active before ours.
LPTOP_LEVEL_EXCEPTION_FILTER g_prevFilter = nullptr;


// Called when a Windows exception occurs.
LONG myUEH(_EXCEPTION_POINTERS *eInfo)
{
  // NOTE: It is not safe to call into the C++ library from an exception
  // handler!  This is here just for ease of demonstration, and should
  // be removed before production usage.
  std::cout << "in myUEH, code: 0x" << std::hex
            << eInfo->ExceptionRecord->ExceptionCode << std::dec
            << std::endl;

  if (g_savedContextIsValid) {
    g_savedContextIsValid = false;

    // Continue execution after where `setjmp` was called.
    //
    // It is not clear whether this is truly safe.  The SUEH docs do
    // not mention this as a valid possibility, but it appears to work.
    //
    // An alternative would be to write system-specific code to copy the
    // register values from `g_savedContext` into `eInfo->ContextRecord`
    // and then return `EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_EXECUTION`.
    //
    std::longjmp(g_savedContext, 1);
  }

  if (g_prevFilter) {
    return g_prevFilter(eInfo);
  }

  // If we return `EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH`, then the dialog box
  // that says "<program> has stopped working" pops up.
  //return EXCEPTION_CONTINUE_SEARCH;

  // If we return `EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER`, then the program
  // terminates with exit code 0xC0000005.  The Cygwin shell interprets
  // that as a "Segmentation fault", while cmd.exe ignores it.
  return EXCEPTION_EXECUTE_HANDLER;
}


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  std::cout << "in main\n";

  if (setjmp(g_savedContext) == 0) {
    // This branch is executed first.
    g_savedContextIsValid = true;

    g_prevFilter = SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(myUEH);
    std::cout << "g_prevFilter: " << (void*)g_prevFilter << "\n";

    // Use the number of command line arguments to decide what bad thing
    // to do.
    if (argc == 1) {
      std::cout << "about to deref null" << std::endl;
      *(((volatile int*)nullptr)) = 0;
    }
    else if (argc == 2) {
      std::cout << "about to fprintf null" << std::endl;
      fprintf(nullptr, "hello");
    }
    else if (argc == 3) {
      std::cout << "about to div by zero" << std::endl;
      volatile int z = 0;
      int q = 2 / z;
      std::cout << "q: " << q << "\n";
    }

    std::cout << "after potential badness\n";
  }

  else {
    // This branch is executed after the call to `longjmp`.

    std::cout << "in recovery code\n";
  }

  // We are past the point where it would be safe to `longjmp` to
  // `g_savedContext`.
  g_savedContextIsValid = false;

  // Restore the old handler (this is not necessary if we are just going
  // to terminate immediately).
  SetUnhandledExceptionFilter(g_prevFilter);

  std::cout << "end of main\n";
  return 0;
}


// EOF

Output:
$ ./catch-segfault.exe
in main
g_prevFilter: 0x7ff70f39c200
about to deref null
in myUEH, code: 0xc0000005
in recovery code
end of main

$ ./catch-segfault.exe 2
in main
g_prevFilter: 0x7ff70f39c200
about to fprintf null
in myUEH, code: 0xc0000005
in recovery code
end of main

$ ./catch-segfault.exe 2 3
in main
g_prevFilter: 0x7ff70f39c200
about to div by zero
in myUEH, code: 0xc0000094
in recovery code
end of main

